# How to forbid break line between list item in markdown

Tags: html, react-native, text, markdown

I have markdown text with bullet list items in my React Native app. For markdown I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-markdown-display. And the vertical spaces between the items are very big. It's look like a few lines. Can you tell me please how can I forbid to make a big vertical break between the items in markdown? Maybe with a special character?
text:

```
Для подключения просим подтвердить ваше согласие:
* На передачу ваших данных (фамилии, имени, отчества, серии и номера паспорта, доверенного номера телефона) VERY BIG SPACES ~~SPECIAL ICON~~ 
* На передачу данных вашего портфеля от УК ~~SPECIAL ICON~~ 
* С [Правилами использования сервиса](https://link)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the markdown input, and the code/library you're using to convert it to HTML? This could also be caused by CSS.

Comment: please can you check, I have renewed my question

Comment: The markdown code looks correct, so it's probably caused by the styling of the list, or by the code that converts this markdown into HTML.

Comment: This is almost certainly caused by a large margin or padding defined in the CSS styles for your list items. To reduce the space between items you would need to reduce the amount of margin and/or padding.